# Syntax highlight for Kotlin-script files in Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, build.gradle, kotlin

I migrated my Gradle project config for Kotlin-script usage: now I have both `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts` and can switch between them configuring `settings.gradle`:

```
project(':myProject').buildFileName='build.gradle.kts'
```

The issue is kts `build.gradle.kts` is not properly highlited: it does not resolve dependencies, says `version = 123` is not a valid word and so on.

I use Idea Ultimate 2017.1.3 and kotlin-plugin 1.1.2. What's the issue? Deleting `build.gradle` doesn't help either.

[gradle-script-kotlin](https://github.com/gradle/gradle-script-kotlin/tree/master/samples) project files are highlited correctly.

Comment: In my case it was sufficient just to update to the latest IDEA Kotlin plugin to fix the issue

Comment: I am having the same question but for android studio. The answer didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The issue probably was I used incorrect gradle version. I recreated the project specifying gradle version 3.5 and now it works fine. Probably I should use gradle wrapper to prevent the same issue occurence on other developers' machines.